# Develop a plugin for Community Builder for Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am using the module Community Builder for Joomla and I have seen in the source code that the `onAfterUserRegistration` event is triggered. So I tried to develop a plugin for this event. Here is what I have done :

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgUserRegistration extends JPlugin
{
    function plgUserRegistration($subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }

    function onAfterUserRegistration()
    {
        //Do some stuff here !
    }
}
```

But my code is never called and I cant figure out why, if someone as any clue!

Comment: I know nothing about Joomla, but it seems to be that you're just defining a class here.  In most plugin systems, you need to actually register the plugin, then have the plugin subscribe to events.  I don't see either of those steps here.  Are they needed in Joomla?

Comment: Yes they are needed but you do that via the backend and I have done it.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but maybe it can help someone else. You must create a CB plugin and not a Joomla plugin.
You can consult the CB Plugin Framework API documentation.

In your php file, you must have something like that :

```
$_PLUGINS->registerFunction( 'onBeforeUserRegistration', 'pluginExampleBeforeUserRegistration' );
/**
* Example registration verify user method
* Method is called before user data is stored in the database
* @param array holds the core mambo user data
* @param array holds the community builder user data
* @param boolean false
*/
function pluginExampleBeforeUserRegistration(&$user,&$cbUser) {
    global $_POST, $_PLUGINS;

    if ($_POST['username'] == $_POST['password']) {
        $_PLUGINS->raiseError(0);
        $_PLUGINS->_setErrorMSG("Password has to be different from username!");
    }
    return true;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I have looked very hard for the CB Plugin Framework API documentation, but have come up empty. It may be behind a pay wall now.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Check whether the plugin is enabled or not.
2. The plugin group must be User, please check that also.

Comment: In addition to Gaurav's answer, by "plugin enabled", he means you have to create a database row in the plugin table.